# How do I add my IP address to the start of my terminal using the bashrc file?

Tags: bash

I want to customise my terminal on an Amazon linux device. 
I have colours using `$(tput setaf 33);`, user name with `/u` but the IP address not there.

```
#blue=$(tput setaf 33);
PS1="\[${blue}]\u$(tput sgr0)"
PS1="${blue}[\u@\w $(tput sgr0)"
PS1+=""
export PS1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... you would need to know what IP address you actually want. Is it a public IP address? Is it a private subnet address? Do you only have 1 IP address? A few things you would need to figure out.

But, if we just assume that we want to have whatever ip address your VM thinks it's address is then:

Add the following to your .bashrc

```
PS1="\[$(tput setaf 33)\][\u@$(ip -4 -o addr show scope global $(ip -4 route | grep default | head -n1 | awk '{print$5}') | awk '{gsub(/\/.*/, "",$4); print $4}' | head -n 1) \w ]\[$(tput sgr0)\] \[$(tput setaf 34)\]\\$\[$(tput sgr0)\] "
```

To throw an IP address into your prompt.

Now, because that's not really human friendly, let's break it down:

Make the prompt blue (honestly I can't remember why I always wrap with `\[ \]` I just remember someone telling me I needed to do that, so I guess see what works for you:

```
\[$(tput setaf 33)\]
```

This bit you already had figured out:

```
[\u@
```

This insanity to find the default IP address, it's a bit hard to break down without just reading through the `ip` man pages but basically we are searching for the interface marked as default then grabbing the IP address and stripping all the extra stuff out with awk/grep/head:

```
$(ip -4 -o addr show scope global $(ip -4 route | grep default | head -n1 | awk '{print$5}') | awk '{gsub(/\/.*/, "",$4); print $4}' | head -n 1)
```

I tend to want to know my ${PWD}:

```
\w ]
```

Reset our colour scheme just to be stafe (I've found weird stuff happens when you keep layering colours without resting:

```
\[$(tput sgr0)\]
```

Set some other colour:

```
\[$(tput setaf 34)\]
```

Set the `$` or `#` prompt which is handy if you want it to be obvious if you are logged in as root:

```
\\$
```

Then reset colour again:

```
\[$(tput sgr0)\]
```